# Cortana Spotify-Controlling

Tags: c#, controls, spotify, cortana

I am trying to work with Cortana I actually can get her own commands and that is working fine! Already my LED-control is working well!

Now I will try to do something like: "Hey Cortana, szenario chilling"

Then my lamps should dim down and I wish that Cortana starts Spotify with a special playlist for chilling.

But I don't find any documentation; how I can remote Spotify from C#.

Have you any ideas?

I have:
- Win10
- Spotify-Desktop
- Visualstuido 2015

Comment: It *seems* that there is no SDK for windows: [see here](https://developer.spotify.com/)